# GTKmm Why the signal_hide() signal doesn't emit correctly?

Tags: c++, gtkmm, emit

I've got a Gtk::Box container (maincontroller) and inside of it, there is a Gtk::Grid (mainmenu). I've added a signal in the maincontroller.cpp like this:

```
mainmenu->signal_hide().connect(
        sigc::mem_fun(this, &MainController::Elmozdulas)
        );
```

When i press a button in the mainmenu, i call the hide() function, what works correctly, i don't see anything after that, but it doesn't emit the signal, only if i close the window. Why is that and how could i fix it?

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider binding to [signal_unmap](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a1f6824bc1524f2586fe066db649fda92) instead. I think signal_hide only gets called if the widget is hidden, not if one of its parents are. Neither of these would be triggered if hide is actually called on a child of mainmenu rather than mainmenu itself. In that case it would appear like mainmenu had been hidden, but would in fact still be visible (and mapped, and realized).